# Android Studio 2.0 Emulator drag and drop won´t work

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-emulator

Since Android Emulator 2.0 this should be supported:

> Drag & Drop
>   With the new emulator, you can not only drag and drop APKs for quick installation, but you can also drag and drop any file to your emulator’s internal SD card to help in testing. [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/12/android-studio-20-preview-android.html)

I have the following problem. When I drop something (like pdf, image or apk) to the emulator at my workplace it won´t work, the mouse icon changes see screenshot.

[image: Drag&Drop won´t work]

It also won´t work for my colleague. But at home at my personal computer it works like charm.

I already changed the avd, to phone, another apk level, with devices frame, nothing works. 
Drag and drop in gernal works on my pc though, if I drag something into chrome (pdf) it will open it as intented.

Answer (score 0):

Please check path of Android Emulator (from Xamarin or another). I think it must be string like *C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk* in Visual Studio:
Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings -> Android SDK Location and change it. Remember to run Visual Studio as administrator.

The next thing is to check paths in register. Press the Windows key and R, enter regedit.exe then find path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Android SDK Tools. Next, check it the value(string) of Path.

Secondly, please repeat for this path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Android Studio and compare current path value to previous value.

I hope this help at the beginning.